# how to handle read access violation?

Tags: visual-c++

sorry for avoiding you guys

i have a problem with reverse function in circular linked list.

```
void reverse() {
    int num = many;
    node* current = head;
    node* previous = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        cout << "1" << '\t';
        node* r = previous;
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
        previous->next = r;
        num--;
    }
    head = previous;
}
```

in this func after 2 while sentence

problem comes up in line that current = current->next;

(exception throw : read access violation,
current was 0xDDDDDDDD)

how to handle it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from Visual Studio trying to help you (and succeeding, IMO).

As Mark Ingraham pointed out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/179910) a long time ago, Visual Studio's runtime library will fill a block of data with 0xDDDDDDDD when you release a block of heap memory.

So, although you haven't shown any code that's deleting from your list, if there is such code, that's probably the first place to look--at least at first glance, it looks like there's a fair chance that when you try erase a node from the list, you're deleting the memory the node lives in, but still leaving a pointer to that deleted memory.

It's also possible (but less likely, IMO) that you're just using memory without initializing it--and you happen to be hitting a block of memory that was previously allocated and then released back to the heap manager.

The bottom line, however, is that you *don't* "handle" the access violation. Instead, you need to find the bug in your code that's leading to the access violation happening, and fix it so that doesn't happen any more.